# What is this 2x4 brick with a 2x3 rounded plate with hole attached?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

[image]

I found this LEGO brick and have no idea what it does, it’s name, or which set it is from. It is a 2x4 brick with a 2x3 base plate with a rounded end and a hole in it.

Can anyone tell me about this brick?

Comment: Great question! Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: For more on the history around the use of these, and the use of glue to attach the figures to some of them, see [this answer here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/994/56).

Answer (score 6):

It's a [magnetic base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=74188c01) that minifigs are attached to.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Isaac, if Alexander has answered your question, you can also click the tick mark below the vote counts :)